# index number of item in items in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to know is there any way for me to get index number (or something) for every item in items using Angular? I need it to use it like item[1], because I need to update scope from iFrame (I managed to connect them, but I cant locate position of item in scope)

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items.body.objects" ...

{
   "body": {
       "objects":[
           {
               id:"2312"
               name: "mighty"
               address: "mighty street 12"
           },
               id:"4252"
               name: "awesome"
               address: "awesome street 12"
           {
           }
       ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `$index` works inside an `ng-repeat` (in HTML).

Comment: whoops, just saw this after posting...

Comment: never mind, I will upvote it anyway :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$index`, e.g.:

```html
<p ng-repeat="item in items.body.objects">
    {{ $index }}
```